# Conditionally split and concat text

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, concatenation

I am trying to conditionally split each of the string in an array.This is my array.

```
const categories = [
  "Department of Natural Science",
  "Department of public health and sanitation",
  "Department of culture and heritage of state"
];
```

Again by splitting each string I want to change it to an array. This array contains several chunk of the string. For eg. by splitting `Department of culture and heritage of state` string I want this to separate `Department of` `Natural` `Science`. Here I want to create every different chunk **if the chunk contains more than 13 character** in length. That's why `Natural` and `Science` separated because if we sum of the length of them it becomes **14** .

Here is what I have tried.

```
const categories = [
  "Department of Natural Science",
  "Department of public health and sanitation",
  "Department of culture and heritage of state"
];

const arrayOfAllString = []; // results at the end

categories.map(cur => {
  // looping the array
  const splitedItems = cur.trim().split(" "); // splitting the current string into words
  const arrayOfSingleString = []; //
  let str = "";
  splitedItems.map(item => {
    // looping the array of splitted words
    if (str.length + item.length > 13) {
      // trying to make a chunk
      arrayOfSingleString.push(str);
      str = ""; // clearing the str because it has been pushed to arrayOfSingleString
    } else {
      str = str.concat(item + " "); // concat the str with curent word
    }
  });
  arrayOfAllString.push(arrayOfSingleString);
});

console.log(arrayOfAllString);
```

My expected result would be somehow look like this :

```
arrayOfAllString = [
  ["Department of", "Natural", "Science"],
  ["Department of", "public health", "and", "sanitation"],
  ["Department of", "culture and", "heritage of", "state"]
];
```

Comment: "more than 13 words in characters in length". None of your strings contain more than 13 words. Can you say what you actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a generator and return chunks in the wanted length.

```js
function* getJoined(string, size) {
    var array = string.split(' '),
        i = 0;

    while (i < array.length) {
        let s = array[i];
        while (++i < array.length && (s + array[i]).length < size) {
            s += ' ' + array[i];
        }
        yield s;
    }
}

console.log([...getJoined('Department of culture and heritage of state', 13)]);
```

Classic approach without missusing `map`.

```js
function getJoined(string) {
    var array = string.split(' '),
        size = 13,
        i = 0,
        result = [];

    while (i < array.length) {
        let s = array[i];
        while (++i < array.length && (s + array[i]).length < size) {
            s += ' ' + array[i];
        }
        result.push(s);
    }
    return result;
}

const categories = ["Department of Natural Science", "Department of public health and sanitation", "Department of culture and heritage of state"];

console.log(categories.map(getJoined));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wow. thanks. what is function* doing? and how that map function is working without doing like .map(cur => getJoined(cur)) ??

Comment: look at [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `map` works with the function directly if the function has the same signature as the wanted callback for mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Made few changes. 
1) while clearing, change to `str = item;` instead of `str = ''`
2) End of loop, do `arrayOfSingleString.push(str);` for adding last item.

```js
const categories = [
  "Department of Natural Science",
  "Department of public health and sanitation",
  "Department of culture and heritage of state"
];

const arrayOfAllString = categories.map(cur => {
  const splitedItems = cur.trim().split(" ");

  const arrayOfSingleString = [];
  let str = "";
  while (splitedItems.length > 0) {
    const item = splitedItems.shift();
    if (str.length + item.length >= 13) {
      // trying to make a chunk
      arrayOfSingleString.push(str);
      // clearing the str because it has been pushed to arrayOfSingleString
      str = item;
    } else {
      // concat the str with curent word
      str = str ? `${str} ${item}` : item;
    }
  }
  arrayOfSingleString.push(str);
  return arrayOfSingleString;
});

console.log(arrayOfAllString);
```

Comment: why there is no space between text ?

Comment: @SandeshSapkota, my bad, I fixed the issue and updated the answer.